# changing Unauthenticated message

Tags: laravel-5

when i ajax call a route with auth middleware i get (while not logged in)

```
{"message":"Unauthenticated."}
```

i want to change this to something like

```
{"stat" : 'er' , 'msg' : 'Unauthenticated' }
```

it seems to be somewhere deep inside vendor ... how can i have this message outside vendor and change it ?

i have to add some extra text to able to post the question so here it is apparently its too short  : some text  some text   some text   some text   some text   some text   some text   some text 
  some text   some text   some text

Comment: You have override the underlying function for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No not inside vendor you need to go to `Handler` Class in `App\Exceptions`
and in `render` function put this before return:

```
     if ($request->expectsJson() && $exception instanceof AuthenticationException)
        return response()->json(["stat" => 'er' , 'msg' => 'Unauthenticated' ], 401);
```

Comment: Don't forget to put use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException at top of the file.

Comment: There is no `render` method in `Handler` class. I'm using Laravel 8.x. Any help please?

Comment: It's `register` method now.
Put this code to achieve what you want

Comment: $this->renderable(function (AuthenticationException $e, $request) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => __('auth.unauthenticated')
            ], 401);
        });

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did mine by adding `$this->renderable(...)` before `$this->reportable(...)`  in the register method within the Handler class for Laravel 9:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

  use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
 use Throwable;

 class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
/**
 * A list of exception types with their corresponding custom log levels.
 *
 * @var array<class-string<\Throwable>, \Psr\Log\LogLevel::*>
 */
protected $levels = [
    //
];

/**
 * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
 *
 * @var array<int, class-string<\Throwable>>
 */
protected $dontReport = [
    //
];

/**
 * A list of the inputs that are never flashed to the session on validation exceptions.
 *
 * @var array<int, string>
 */
protected $dontFlash = [
    'current_password',
    'password',
    'password_confirmation',
];

/**
 * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{

    $this->renderable(function (AuthenticationException $e, $request) {
         return response()->json([ 'message' => __('auth.unauthenticated') ], 401);
         });

        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {

    });
}
```

}